# How to best architect website when each client has own database and subdomain?

Tags: asp.net

For client security and privacy reasons, we want to deploy a unique database for each client while using the same website.

I envision that during the session_start event, we would determine which database to use for them (by looking at the subdomain they come in on) and set the connection string in a session variable.  Then on every page_init, we'd dynamically set any object's connection string.  In code behind, we'd do the same thing with the connection string.

Is there a better approach to doing this and will setting the connection string in page_init work?  Is using a session variable wise?  I've tended not to ever use them except when no other solution was possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the model itself it is really complex and can let you with some errors specially when we are talking about changes in the database. Imagine that you need to add an extra field on the interface. if you have 100 clients this will mean updating 100 different databases. when we talk about dealing with downtime them things get even worst.

I would do with that in a light different abstract your database layer create one api that will call the database. And from the website you always call the api passing the domain that you want the data to come from.

You can ask me what advantage this will give to you. The biggest one that you will see it is when doing upgrades and maintenance. Having one api per client it is a lot better to think them having one database per client. and if you really want to have just one (I would really recommend having one per client and deploying automatically) you can have a switch on the call and base with some parameters that you pass to the api ( can be on the header like the subdomain on the header) you can chose what database to connect.

Let me give you a sample scenario and how I would suggest to approach this scenario (that is true for database or api)

I want to include a new data field. So first thing it is to add this field on the backend (api or database) deploy this new field if it is one api you can even test that calling the api and see that the new field it is now returned that is not a problem for your ui because it is just a field that it does not use. after that you change the ui to actually use this field and deploy that to production.

Comment: Thanks, this is good stuff.  How would you access an API data source in a control?  For example, let's say I have a drop down listbox on the page that has a sql datasource control for the data.  How would something like this work?

Comment: Always use object datasource if you still using webforms. If you agree on the answer can you mark it as answered? ;)